# How do you configure SSIS packages on the server to use configuration files when using Execute Package Task

Tags: azure, ssis

Simple scenario. I have 3 SSIS packages. 
Package #1. Executes to determine the existence of a file. If the file is present it runs an Execute Package task to call the other 2 packages to run
Package #2. Performs a data import task from one source
Package #3. Performs a data import task from another source

All the packages have the Package Configuration option enabled and I use configuration files stored in a single shared location on the file system; and configured each package to use the configuration files at runtime.

When I execute the process within VS, everything works as expected.

So I copy the packages to a server, create an SQL job to call the main package. When I execute the job the main package executes fine and uses the configuration file to establish connections leverage other settings within the config file.

But when calls are make within the main package to run the other 2 packages (which also reside on the file system) using the Execute Package task; the other packages fail. When I examine the logs, it suggests that the child packages are failing because they cannot find connections and variables that I've defined in the configuration files.

So it would seem that the configuration files are not being used by the child packages although I defined them within those package prior to the deploy.

I believe the main package finds the configuration file because I have explicitly pointed to the configuration file location within the SQL job.

How can I ensure that the packages that get called by the main package use the configuration files on the file system?

I am using an Azure VM.

Comment: Why are you using legacy mode package deployment?

Comment: The new project mode deployment (SQL Server 2012 and later) allows parameters at both project level and package level, which are much easier than old-style configuration files.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the SSIS, Configuration menu as well as a sample job definition?

Comment: @billinkc, due to the urgent nature I modified the package to circumvent the issue. So instead of calling the Execute Package Task for the other 2 packages, I replaced the Execute Package tasks with the actual content of the child packages and everything works now. So I don't have screenshots of the previous configuration now. Thanks.